# ¿Como enviar un audio (.mp3) con Multicast java?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una estructura cliente-servidor para mandar un audio empleando el MulticastSocket en java, pero no encuentro mi error, ya intente de varias forma pero no me funciona, esta es la ultima modificación que le hice al codigo sin exito. No me manda ningun error de compilacion, pero no recibe la cancion correctamemte, ya que si crea el archivo como se lo especifico pero con 0 bytes.

**Servidor**

```
    public class ServidorMulticast {
        
        private MulticastSocket servidor;
        private DatagramPacket paquete;
        private InetAddress ip_grupo;
        private byte[] buffer2;
        private ByteBuffer buffer;
        private FileOutputStream fil;
        
        public ServidorMulticast(){
            try{
                servidor = new MulticastSocket(3000);
                //Establecer direccion IP multicast
                ip_grupo = InetAddress.getByName("224.10.10.25");
                //Unirse al grupo
                servidor.joinGroup(ip_grupo);
                
                
    //            buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
                this.fil = new FileOutputStream("Practica5/Musica.mp3");
                this.buffer2 = new byte[1024];
                
                while(true){
                    paquete = new DatagramPacket(buffer2, buffer2.length);
                    servidor.receive(paquete);
                    
                }
                
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
```

**Cliente**

```
    public class ClienteMulticast {
        
        private MulticastSocket cliente;
        private DatagramPacket paquete;
        private InetAddress ip_grupo;
        private byte[] buffer2;
        private ByteBuffer buffer;
        private FileInputStream fil;
        
        public ClienteMulticast(){
            File file = new File("Musica.mp3");
            long peso = file.length();
            
            try{
                
                this.fil = new FileInputStream(file);
                this.buffer2 = new byte[512];
                
                cliente = new MulticastSocket(3000);
                //Generar IP del grupo
                ip_grupo = InetAddress.getByName("224.10.10.25");
                //Unirse al grupo
                cliente.joinGroup(ip_grupo);
                
                
                while(this.fil.read(this.buffer2) != -1 ){
                    //Creamos un nuevo paquete
                    buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap((""+peso).getBytes());
                    paquete = new DatagramPacket(buffer2, buffer2.length,ip_grupo,3000);
                    cliente.send(paquete);
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }
                
                cliente.leaveGroup(ip_grupo);
                cliente.close();
                
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ClienteMulticast cliente = new ClienteMulticast();
            
        }
    
    }
```